# How to give the recursive definition of set A consisting of arbitrary nested, properly matched brackets

Tags: recursive-algorithms

Like for example {}[{()}] $ \in$B, but {( $ \notin $ B. We have these brackets available: {}()[].

I dont know how to do this since i cant come up with a base case and the induction case. Most of the times there was something like n, or something with numbers. How to give the recursive definition of this set?

Answer (score 0):

You can build any matched string by concatenating two matched strings or by putting a matched set of brackets around a matched string.  The base case is the empty string.

Comment: How would i formulate my base and my induction part then?

Comment: I don't know what language you have available to express it.  Do you use [Backus Naur form?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)